# Code not working - upper and lower - Python

Tags: python, uppercase, lowercase

The  below is my code, and as you can guess, I am trying to change the input's first to upper, and rest to lower.

```
name = input("Your name: ")
name.lower()
name[0].upper()
print(name)
```

But on the interpreter I get the exact same variable!

Comment: Strings are immutable. A **new** string is returned instead.

Comment: You need to store result into a variable. `l_name=name.lower()`

Comment: `print(name[0].upper()+name[1:].lower())`

Comment: While the linked "duplicate answer" is helpful for people who know what they're doing, I think it may be a step beyond the question here. Is there another question where the answer is simply "Store the result in a variable" instead of "here's why you have to store the result in a variable"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its what that [`str.capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) is for :

```
>>> name='name'
>>> name.capitalize()
'Name'
```

*Note* that your command `name[0].upper()` just return the first character in upper mode!

Comment: Ahem! Link the module to help the OP!

Comment: @AvinashRaj Waiting for the day we all get the same bandwidth! (I joined the race too)

Comment: as we see in the beginning of the list we "hope" it was upper lol